# Add scroll bar for linear layout?

Tags: android

I need to add a scroll for linear layout.I use the following code to create the linear layout.But it's not working

```
LinearLayout llay=new LinearLayout(context);
    llay.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

If i use the following lines i will get the Scrollbar.

```
ScrollView sc=new ScrollView(context);
sc.addView(llay);
```

But I need to add scroll for the Linear layout without using ScrollView.
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: A scrollview is the standard way of having a layout scroll and display a scrollbar. Care to tell why you can't use it?

Comment: was my answer not right?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `ScrollView`. Please look at this short tutorial on how to do it:

[Android Scrollview Example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example)ew